# Textbox scroll to bottom in Avalonia

Tags: avaloniaui

I have a textbox that I write info to that automatically creates a scroll bar when the screen is filled, and I'd like to scroll to the bottom of it. It seems like what I need to do is set the scrollbar Offset to some vector, but my problem is finding the ScrollViewer.

I can't use FindControl because it's not named anywhere in the xaml, and I can only change a few values using textbox.SetValue

Comment: I don't actually think we have a good solution for this. Could you add an issue over at https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia and I'll try and get something in for the next release?

Comment: sure, I just added it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to scroll a `TextBox` currently is to set the `CaretPosition`. For example to scroll to the end of the text you could use:

```
textbox.CaretIndex = int.MaxValue;
```

Comment: great, that works though the scrollbar itself doesnt get updated until you use it, but good enough for now!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore

Answer (score 1):

For me it works only when I set `textbox.CaretIndex` to the length of the text. Assuming that property `Logs` (string type) is binded to textbox I used this

```
textbox.CaretIndex = Logs.Length
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
textbox.CaretIndex = textbox.Text?.Length ?? 0;
```

Though, it can be slow, so I recommend to access the child `ScrollViewer` and call its `ScrollToEnd()`.

Something like this:

```
// call this once and store it somewhere
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = textBox.GetVisualDescendants()
                                   .OfType<ScrollViewer>()
                                   .FirstOrDefault();

...

scrollViewer?.ScrollToEnd();
```

But in order to get the `ScrollViewer`, you should make sure that the text box is loaded.